# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined `npm run build`

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I am doing `npm run build` in my **create-react-app** project, it is failing and the log in not very helpful.

HERE -> [image of the npm log](https://pasteboard.co/JotrBGR.png)

Here is the problem in text format.

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! card_builder@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the card_builder@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
```

**My app is working fine in development mode (i.e. at `npm start`)**

Here is the link of the code sandbox url -> https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-read-propery-type-of-undefined-problem-with-react-scripts-build-6riyp

*Built using create-react-app*

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error might comes from an empty CSS rule somewhere, most probably.
It might come from a dependency, so that might get tricky.

First thing to do would be to try to remove css file one by one from your project to spot which one as the issue. If you can't find it, then it comes from a dependency, and you best bet would be to remove `empty-rules` rule from CSSLint or from the linter you are using.

Resource: https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-empty-rules

Comment: thanks a lot
It found it out. I found the problem in [Main.css](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-read-propery-type-of-undefined-problem-with-react-scripts-build-6riyp?file=/src/Containers/stylesheets/Main.css) which was linked with [Main.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-read-propery-type-of-undefined-problem-with-react-scripts-build-6riyp?file=/src/Containers/Main.js). Can you please tell me which part actually has the problem here? 