# problem in css file - issue with empty css rules?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I tested over each css file in my project which gave me [this error](https://pasteboard.co/JotrBGR.png) and finally found which file it was.

I found the problem in [Main.css](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-read-propery-type-of-undefined-problem-with-react-scripts-build-6riyp?file=/src/Containers/stylesheets/Main.css) which was linked with [Main.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-read-propery-type-of-undefined-problem-with-react-scripts-build-6riyp?file=/src/Containers/Main.js)

**It would be very helpful if someone could tell me this *where* exactly is the error in [Main.css](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-read-propery-type-of-undefined-problem-with-react-scripts-build-6riyp?file=/src/Containers/stylesheets/Main.css)**

Originally asked here : [Cannot read property 'type' of undefined CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined `npm run build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636881/cannot-read-property-type-of-undefined-compileerror-begins-at-css-selector-un)

Comment: line 19 remove the `deg` unit: `transform: rotate3d(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your CSS through the [CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) will give us the following output: [image: css validator output]

From this, I went to the [`rotate3d` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d) and saw that it requires 4 arguments. While browsers seem to understand it with only 1 argument as long as it is 0 without a unit (from the first example on that page), it is a best practice to provide all 4 arguments `rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: *I am very grateful to you*. Now `build` can be created.
I thought that this wouldn't have been solved.
**Thanks a lot for solving this and helping me**

Comment: please mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem :)